# How do I change a compound path back to text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to edit my designer's artwork by changing the "5" into a "4". I have the font installed already.

When I try to open the design file in AI and highlight the "5", to my surprise it isn't a text object. It looks like it's something called a compound path. How would I update it's type so I can type "4" in it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't.**

Once text has been converted to outlines, there is no feature or ability to convert it from outlines back to live, editable, text.

(Other than choosing `Undo` immediately after you've converted the text to outlines. However, if the file has been closed and then reopened, there's nothing which with invert the outline function.)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do is to use the font you have installed are re-type the "4" in the same color and position.

Or, with a bit more in-depth AI knowledge you could actually draw the "4" by hand, it would only take a few minutes if its really that important.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem although i'm completely new to illustrator. I just need to change the text of the designer. How exactly do you do that?